# .htaccess to match paramaterized URLS

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, cache, ajax, mod-cache

I am trying to set a cache control header when a browser requsets the following url:

```
www.example.com/php/getData.php?exampleField=exampleValue
```

As even though getData.php is a dynamic page, when the parameter `exampleField` equals `exampleValue` the response doesnt change. Therefore, there is no reason for the browser not to cache this result. My question is how do I write a `FilesMatch` rule in the .htaccess file to match this, I tried the following with no luck:

```
<FilesMatch "php/getData.php\?exampleField=(exampleValue1|exampleValue2)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3024000, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 1):

The GET parameters are not part of the filename, so `<FilesMatch>` will not match them.

Given that you are serving up a PHP file, have you considered simply adding the cache control header there?

```
<?php
  /* ... */
  if (
    @isset( $_GET['exampleField'] ) &&
    $_GET['exampleField'] == 'exampleValue'
  ) {
    header('Cache-Control "max-age=3024000, must-revalidate"');
  }
  /* ... */
?>
```

Comment: hmm I will give this a try tonight